# how can I use sed to replace blank fields in a csv file, with a string

Tags: file, bash, csv, sed

I am currently working on a script which processes csv files, and I am trying to make the script replace all blank fields in the csv file, with a string "data_n/a". Initially I had thought I could simply use the following to accomplish this task:

```
sed -e "s/hi/data_n\/a/g"
```

but unfortunately that would leave out any empty fields that could possibly occur at the beginning or the end of the lines of the csv file. I am not sure how to go about this, so I was wondering if anyone could help push me in the right direction or offer advice as to what I should do? thanks!

also here is a sample of the csv file:

```
,,6004,,,15:00.00,30004,Colleen,2010-02-10
2,Closed,6005,,,30:00.00,30005,Rich,2010-02-11
7,Closed,6001,,,30:00.00,10001,Mary Beth,2010-02-11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **perl** regex,

```
   perl -pe 's;^,|,$|(?<=,),;data_n\/a,;g' input.cvs
```

Using **sed**,

```
$ sed -r 's;^,|,$;data_n\/a,;g
:l
s;,,;,data_n\/a,;g
t l' input.cvs
```

Comment: This does not replace the last field, example

Answer (score 2):

If **awk** is an option, you can try the following:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i==""){printf "data_n/a"}else{printf $i} if(i<NF)printf ","} printf "\n"}' infile
```

Comment: although I had ended up going with the sed answer, the awk solution that you have posted worked just as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the ^ indicates beginning of line and $ is end of the line

```
sed "s/,,/data_n\/a,/g;s/^,/data_n\/a,/;s/,$/,data_n\/a/" file >outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(^,)|(,)(,)|(,)$/\2\4data_n\/a\1\3/g;ta' file
```