# substitute consecutive tabs for "\tNA\t"

Tags: linux, awk, gsub

Have a badly formatted tsv file with empty fields all over the place. I wish to fill these empty spaces with "NA" on linux.

I tried `awk '{gsub("\t\t","\tNA\t"); print$0)'` but that only substitutes one empty space to NA instance. Chaining the command `awk '{gsub("\t\t","\tNA\t"); print$0)|awk '{gsub("\t\t","\tNA\t"); print$0)` does two substitutions per line - but not particularly helpful if I have many columns to deal with.

Is there a faster (neater) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit complex since you have to handle newlines empty fields, end of line empty fields and potentially successive empty fields. I could not achieve something with sed, it's probably insane. But with awk this seems to work:

```
$ cat test.txt
a       c   d   e
    g   h   i   j
k   l   m   n   
p           s   t
        w   x   

$ awk -F$'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i==""){printf "NA"}else{printf $i} if(i<NF)printf "\t"} printf "\n"}' test.txt 
a   NA  c   d   e
NA  g   h   i   j
k   l   m   n   NA
p   NA  NA  s   t
NA  NA  w   x   NA
```

Beware copy paste, the tabs will probably be transformed to spaces... By the way I searched a solution for the CSV files, and adapted it from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656215/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-blank-fields-in-a-csv-file-with-a-string) ;) where you can see that the most readable option is the awk one.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with sed? For example:

```
cat test.txt
test        test        test
test        test        test

sed 's:\t\t*:\tNA\t:g' test.txt

test    NA  test    NA  test
test    NA  test    NA  test
```

Comment: I tried but in cases of consecutive tabs, it only replaces the first.

Comment: Did you try with global g parameter?

Comment: yes. :( I copied your line into the command line and checked the output.

Comment: You command below and mine give the same output. May be I'm missing something with your file?

Comment: I'm going to guess my file had several instances of multiple consecutive tabs and lines which start with a tab. The former results in only the first \t\t substituting for \tNA\t (I assume in the case of \t\t\t, the line substitutes the first two \t but leaves the third alone, resulting in \tNA\t\t); the latter requires `awk '{ gsub(/\t\t/,"\tNA\t")` - which of course I'm sure has a sed equivalent (sorry I'm not programming trained, so I'm not familiar with these terms).

Comment: You can pipe commands to remove leading tabs or spaces and do replacement: `sed -e $'s/^[ \t]*//' test.txt | sed $'s:\t\t*:\tNA\t:g'`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this works:
`awk '{ gsub(/\t\t\t/,"\tNA\tNA\t"); print $0}' test.txt | awk '{ gsub(/\t\t/,"\tNA\t"); print $0}' |  awk '{ gsub(/\t\t/,"\tNA\t"); print
 $0}' | awk '{gsub(/^[\t]+/,"NA\t"); print $0}'`

interestingly this doesn't:
`awk '{ gsub(/\t\t\t/,"\tNA\tNA\t"); print $0}' test.txt | awk '{ gsub(/\t\t/,"\tNA\t"); print $0}' |  awk '{gsub(/^[\t]+/,"NA\t"); print 
$0}'`

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution though..